# Copying to a dynamically-allocated array in C

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, copy, allocation

I'm trying to copy to a dynamically-allocated array in C (The source array may or may not be dynamically allocated. The first element of the array is copied correctly, but the rest is not. Can anyone tell what I'm doing wrong?

Here's where I'm calling the method:

```
vec3 tempVel = {
    (float)rand()/(float)RAND_MAX * (2.0f * INIT_VELOCITY_DIMENSION_MAGNITUDE) - INIT_VELOCITY_DIMENSION_MAGNITUDE,
    (float)rand()/(float)RAND_MAX * (2.0f * INIT_VELOCITY_DIMENSION_MAGNITUDE) - INIT_VELOCITY_DIMENSION_MAGNITUDE,
    (float)rand()/(float)RAND_MAX * (2.0f * INIT_VELOCITY_DIMENSION_MAGNITUDE) - INIT_VELOCITY_DIMENSION_MAGNITUDE
};
thisBoid->velocity = copyArrays2(&tempVel, 3);
```

And the method:

```
vec3* copyArrays2(vec3 *src, int len){

    vec3 *tempArray = (vec3*)malloc(len*sizeof(vec3));
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++){
        *tempArray[i] = *src[i];
    }

    return tempArray;
}
```

Printing the values of 'tempVel' before copying and 'thisBoid->velocity' afterwards gives the following output:

```
{0.895216, -0.107424, 0.532019}
{0.895216, 10.000000, 0.500000}
```

Comment: EDIT: 10 and .5 are always copied regardless of the contents of tempVel

Comment: your "array" has only one element...

Comment: There's no way this compiles, you're dereferencing a `vec3`... @iharob ..."please" ? :)

Comment: tempVel? It has 3 floats that are separated by commas. A vec3 object inherently has 3 elements

Comment: @Quentin it actually does compile

Comment: [Do not cast the return value of `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/1983495), and use [`memcpy()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html)

Comment: @Quentin I do not think so!

Comment: Probably `*tempArray[i] = *src[i];` --> `tempArray[i] = src[i];`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I tried that, I get the error:     "array type 'vec3' (aka 'float [3]') is not assignable"

Comment: @user3638238 The confusion stems from the fact that we did not know that `vec3` was actually a typedef for `float[3]`... Which now makes sense.

Comment: @user3638238 `tempVel` is one `vec3`, not `vec3[len]`

Comment: if output as `{0.895216, -0.107424, 0.532019}
{0.895216, 10.000000, 0.500000}`, `vec3 tempVel[] ={{0.895216, -0.107424, 0.532019}, {0.895216, 10.000000, 0.500000}}; thisBoid->velocity = copyArrays2(tempVel, 2);`

Comment: @Quentin that is correct, sorry about that. So how would I go about accessing the ith index of a vec3?

Comment: @user3638238 just like Peter Schneider did, use the subscript (`[]`) operator. Or, as hinted by iharob, calculate the total size of your array and use `memcpy`.

Comment: @user3638238 I had assumed like as `typedef struct vec3 { float v[3]; } vec3;`

Answer (score 1):

`*tempArray[i]` is the first element of the i'th vec3.

[Operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) makes that it is evaluated `*(tempArray[i])` , i.e. `tempArray[i][0]`. Only the first element of each vec3 is touched. If vec3 is a plain array in disguise you'll have to iterate through its elements in an inner loop.

Example code, provided `typedef float vec3[3];`:

```
for(int i=0; i<len; i++){
   for(int ii=0; ii<3; ii++){
        tempArray[i][ii] = src[i][ii];
    }
}
```

Btw, I would like to use this opportunity to thank iharob for his constructive comments.